# Who is the artist that painted the '9 Stages of Samatha Meditation' painting?

Tags: meditation, samatha, tibetan, stages

The following Tibetan Buddhist (thangka) painting is a visual representation of the 9 Stages (~11 stages) of Samatha meditation. Who painted it?

[image]

Comment: This is not really the place to ask such questions that a web search can find. This is a place to ask and inquire about the Buddhas/Buddhist teachings.

Comment: @Remyla what if a web search doesn't provide the author?  it's a nice work, too many colors imo, but whatever...it's fair game imo

Comment: This particular version seems to originate from [this online store based in Nepal](https://traditionalartofnepal.com/shop/medicine-thangka/samatha-thangka-painting/).